# Not able to install apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-14.04

I am not able to install apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

On executing

`sudo apt-get install apache2` getting the below error:-

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

As mentioned in the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/611354/error-installing-apache2) I tried doing `apt-get upgrade -f`.

Also the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep -i ^apache2`

```
apache2                     deinstall
apache2-doc                 install
apache2-utils                   install
apache2.2-common                deinstall
```

Output of `apt-mark unhold apache2-bin`
`apache2-bin was already not hold`

Output of `apt-cache depends apache2`

```
apache2
  Depends: lsb-base
  Depends: procps
    procps:i386
  Depends: perl
  Depends: mime-support
  Depends: apache2-bin
  Depends: apache2-data
  Suggests: <www-browser>
    arora
    dillo
    dwb
    lynx-cur:i386
    lynx-cur
    netsurf
    netsurf-fb
    netsurf-gtk
    uzbl
    chimera2
    chromium-browser
    elinks
    epiphany-browser
    firefox
    google-chrome-beta
    google-chrome-stable
    google-chrome-unstable
    konqueror
    links
    links2
    midori
    netrik
    rekonq
    surf
    w3m:i386
    w3m
    xemacs21-mule
    xemacs21-mule-canna-wnn
    xemacs21-nomule
 Suggests: apache2-doc
 |Suggests: apache2-suexec-pristine
  Suggests: apache2-suexec-custom
  Suggests: ufw
  Suggests: apache2-utils
    apache2-utils:i386
  Recommends: ssl-cert
  Conflicts: apache2.2-common
  Conflicts: <apache2.2-common:i386>
  Replaces: apache2.2-common
  Replaces: <apache2.2-common:i386>
  Conflicts: apache2:i386
```

Output of `apt-cache policy apache2 apache2-bin`

```
apache2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4
  Version table:
     2.4.16-4+deb.sury.org~precise+4 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4.7-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
apache2-bin:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.4.7-1ubuntu4
  Version table:
     2.4.7-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Output of `sudo aptitude -f install apache2`

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin{a} apache2-data{a} libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3{ab} libaprutil1-ldap{ab} 
0 packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,106 kB of archives. After unpacking 4,703 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 : Depends: libaprutil1 (= 1.5.3-1) but 1.5.4-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 is installed.
 libaprutil1-ldap : Depends: libaprutil1 (= 1.5.3-1) but 1.5.4-1+deb.sury.org~precise+1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     apache2 [Not Installed]                            
2)     apache2-bin [Not Installed]                        
3)     libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 [Not Installed]            
4)     libaprutil1-ldap [Not Installed]                   



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Can some one help what is going wrong?

Comment: same problem here :(

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I face the similar problem when upgrading Ubuntu 12.04.x to 14.04.x with custom PPA that used to upgrade PHP5 previously.

I trace into the problem and found the package that having problem which is libaprutil1.

I try the following and it fixes my issue

```
apt-get remove libaprutil1
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install apache2
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it  with this commands

```
sudo apt-get -f autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

than try again :

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey i had the same problem about months ago!
Try this:

```
apt-get --purge remove apache2
apt-get autoremove
rm -rf /etc/apache2/
apt-get clean
apt-get update
```

After that you can try to install it again.
I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Not working still getting the same error. `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`

Answer (score 0):

When asked, don't accept the given solution so that aptitude, next, offer an alternative where it will install `apache-bin` which is the unmet dependency as the error shows.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently solved this issue.

```
----------------issue-----------------------
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.7-1ubuntu4) but 2.4.29-1ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

First, remove the apache2-bin from the ubuntu as

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2-bin
```

now install apache-bin2

```
sudo apt install apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

It can happen when your system has dependencies with different versions than the required.
In my case, i removed the dependencies and then installed.

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2-bin
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```